# ListView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, landscape

So I am aware that I can't use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`, because `ScrollView` gets the focus in that case and `ListView` becomes non-scrollable. But I have a program that goes out of screen when in landscape mode and I need to be able to scroll down to see the rest of the program so I use `LinearLayout(vertical)` with `ScrollView` that contains the most of the program and under that `ScrollView` I got my `ListView`. Now I want to be able to scroll down to my `ListView` when I am in landscape mode but it won't let me do that, it stops me where `ListView` begins. Is there a some kind of solution for this, or is it better for me to make my program stay in portrait mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still trying to nest a ListView inside a ScrollView in landscape mode...

I suggest creating a new **landscape** specific layout with two columns: the *left hand* side contains UI elements inside the ScrollView and the *right hand* side contains the ListView. This way both Views will still support scrolling.

Simply save this new layout in a new folder `res/layout-land` with the *same file name* as the portrait layout in `res/layout`.  The OS will automatically switch layouts when the orientation changes.

You can read more about this: [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

This end result will be similar to the old Google Market image:

[image: Goole Market Landscape]

The left, green side can scroll if necessary and the right, white side will scroll as well.

Comment: Even though this wasn't the answer I was looking for, after some research I found out that this is indeed the best solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do away with the VerticalLayout and insert the rest of the content as header and footer views of the ListView